# Is there a Regex to trim numbers after two decimal places?

Tags: c, regex, alteryx

I am trying to reduce the number of decimals and for some reason, using a "fixed decimal" 258.2 does not change all numbers in my column to two decimal places.

Pretty much I have the following after specifying the number as a fixed decimal with 2 places:

1. 6.933141
2. 5.13
3. 1.56
4. 2.94
5. 1.54
6. 6.470931

So changing the amount of fixed decimals did not do it for me, so I have been trying to use RegEx, and came up with `(^\d+.\d{2})`. This however only identifies what I want to keep.

Is there a way to do this using Regex_Replace?

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use the `printf` format `%.2f` to print with 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```c
^(\d+\.\d{2})\d+$
```

**Replacement**: `$1`. See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/KP8U9J/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of $1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```